# my DIY trim function cannot return correct answer, it returns undefied

Tags: javascript, return, undefined

I am trying to create a function named "trim" to delete the blanks at the head and the tail of an input string. (I know String.prototype.trim can do the same work, I'm just practicing my JS) but it return "undefined",can you help me?

```js
function trim(str) {
    if (str.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        str = str.slice(1);
        trim(str);
    } else if (str.charAt(str.length - 1) === ' ') {
        str = str.slice(0, -1);
        trim(str);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}

console.log(trim('  ab c '));
```

Comment: you need to `return trim(str)` in the first two blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return` from every place you are recursing, in order to make sure that you have returns all the way back up the stack to the original caller.  See the snippet below.

```js
function trim(str) {
    if (str.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        str = str.slice(1);
        return trim(str);
    } else if (str.charAt(str.length - 1) === ' ') {
        str = str.slice(0, -1);
        return trim(str);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}

console.log(trim('  ab c '));
```

Some more context:

Every time you call `trim` from inside the body of the `trim` function, you are [recursing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion).  If you take the string `' hello '` and call `trim` as (`trim(' hello ')`), the following occurs:

1. Call `trim(' hello ')`.
2. First `if` condition is met-- string is sliced and `trim('hello ')` is called.
3. Second `if` condition is met-- string is `trim('hello')` is called.
4. No `if` condition is met-- `else` block is entered ` 'hello' is returned.

So our call stack is `trim(' hello ') ==> trim('hello ') ==> trim('hello')`.  However, in the function as you originally wrote it, only the last call to `trim` (`trim('hello')`) actually returns a value to the previous caller-- the other invocations of `trim` return nothing (`undefined`).  In order to make sure that the value return is passed all the way back up to the original caller of `trim(' hello ')`, you need to make sure that every time you recurse you `return` the result of the recursion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about the sentence "in order to make sure that you have returns all the way back up the stack to the original caller", can you explain more? Thank you very much.

Comment: @toggler - I provided some more context in the answer, please see if that helps.

Comment: I think I understand now. It just like:

        function fn1(){
            function fn2(){
                return 1;
            }
            fn2();
        }
    
       fn1(); //undefined
before you explained to me, I thought one "return" can pass through the chain of callers. Now I know I was wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, your summary is correct-- you've got it now.  Glad to help.  If the answer was sufficiently helpful, you can mark it "accepted" in order to let other visitors know it worked for you.  However, you are under no obligation to do so if it fell short in any way.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You are returning your `str` only on `else` clause. You have to return in every case:

```
function trim(str) {
    if (str.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        str = str.slice(1);
        trim(str);
    } else if (str.charAt(str.length - 1) === ' ') {
        str = str.slice(0, -1);
        trim(str);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I think you might want revisit this answer-- if you call it with `" hello "` it returns `"hello "`, with the trailing space not trimmed.